# My JFrame is blank when I invoke a object at frist start

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I saw a strange one thing. When I run a code in a debug mode and invoke this line by clicking the button:

```
 popup.setVisible(true);
```

I see a blank window (`popupConfig`) without my context. What can I do to show my `popupConfig` all at once by using: this `popupVisible(true)`?

**Main**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class PopupConfig  extends JFrame 
{
    private final static Color backgroundColor = new Color(0 , 51 , 102);
    
    private final static Font customeFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD , 18);
    
    public PopupConfig() 
    {
        setTitle("TEST");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setSize(600 ,500);
        setLocation(400 , 400);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(backgroundColor);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblSeting = new JLabel("SETTINGS");
        lblSeting.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblSeting.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 42));
        lblSeting.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblSeting.setSize( 331 , 49 );
        lblSeting.setLocation( 114 , 11 );
        getContentPane().add(lblSeting, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

**PopupConfig**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class PopupConfig  extends JFrame 
{
    private final static Color backgroundColor = new Color(0 , 51 , 102);
    private final static Font customeFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD , 18);

    public PopupConfig() 
    {
        setTitle("TEST");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setSize(600 ,500);
        setLocation(400 , 400);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(backgroundColor);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblSeting = new JLabel("SETTINGS");
        lblSeting.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblSeting.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 42));
        lblSeting.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblSeting.setSize( 331 , 49 );
        lblSeting.setLocation( 114 , 11 );
        getContentPane().add(lblSeting, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

**Window**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private JButton btn;
    private PopupConfig popup;
    
    public Window()
    {
        setTitle("TEST");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setSize(600 ,500);
        setLocation(400 , 400);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,51,102) );
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         
        btn = new JButton("TEST");
        
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        btn.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
        add(btn);
        
        popup = new PopupConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        popup.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I run a code in a debug mode ..." - does this also mean you're using some breakpoints and your code is stopping there? In that case you're probably blocking the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Exactly. The above code is a shorter version of the project. In the original project I check in other part of code whether my "popup"(JFrame) is opended. Do you know how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Well, don't block the EDT :) You might want to learn about the EDT and how to avoid blocking it but in general if you're stopping at a break point the UI also is stopped and won't render anything (because that happens on the EDT).

Comment: Code works fine for me. I see a second frame with a "Settings" label. Other comments: 1) don't call you class Window, there is an AWT component with that name so it gets confusing. 2) Don't use a JFrame for a popup. An application should only have a single JFrame. For a popup window use a JDialog. 3) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: *"using layout manger could be annoying"* Not using a layout manager *will** be annoying, unmaintainable, and reduce the number of people willing to help. BTW - you seemed to be trying to tag @camickr in the 'not an answer' below. It has been flagged and will likely soon be deleted. Keep that section for answers and put comments her in the comment section.

Comment: BTW *"Link: https://ibb.co/.."* What is that a link to? Most people around here won't visit links, especially links where it's not obvious as to what the link leads to). Some SO helpers are using company networks and *cannot* follow links (because there are only a limited number of sites allowed by company security).